# How should I install packages while working with a large number of virtual environments?

Tags: python, package, virtualenv, pypi, python-venv

Let's say I need to make 10 small projects with NumPy so I am making 10 virtual envs. Do I need to "pip install numpy" every time?

I know that for any project in python it's  recommended to work on a Virtual enviroment so I want to work on it. But I don't want to install libraries every time, it takes a lot time on my laptop.

Is there any more effective way to work with venv ?

Comment: Maybe use anaconda (conda) to manage virtual environments. It won't install a package again if its already installed (only if the version is different).

Comment: @DiegoPalacios I haven't used anaconda before but it seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks